# QGIS vector layer attribute table update using CSV - JOIN not working

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, csv, attribute-joins

I have an existing vector layer which I have added features to and updated the geometry existing features.  The associated attribute table has 34 FIELDS (with 25 features).  I'm trying to undertake a bulk update of the attribute table by merging a non geometric CSV file, ie. I want to over-write the current attribute table fields with the updated CSV values.

Basically I have exported the existing attribute table and updated in Excel and re-saved as CSV.  I've added updated CSV as delimited text layer and it appears correctly.  However, when I'm utilising the JOIN (from vector layer properties) I end up with the current fields + 34 new fields (with heading prefixed by csv filename or custom prefix).  25 feature rows remain.

eg. JOIN field and TARGET field are linked by a FIELD OBJECTID.  This is a 4 digit number.
CSV FIELD headings all match the TARGET (since attribute table export to CSV)
Current workaround (that isn't working!) is to add custom prefix character for JOIN fields, delete original fields and try to batch process rename fields removing custom prefix character but batch process is stalling / locking up after processing around 6 of 34 fields.

Is JOIN the right command/tool or should I be trying some other form of merge to overwrite the current table?

Comment: You could create a new layer with just the join field left in it.  Then do the join and export that to a new layer.  You might then just need to delete the join field of the csv.

Comment: Thanks will give that a try.  I guess the fundamental question really boils down to should JOIN function overwrite existing data?

Comment: your proposed process to batch process remove custom prefix character - doesn't sound possible on the original source.